# how to wait for http request for returning response with in subscribe method in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, asp.net-core

In my case ill get data but the data did not sort according to the request I want when I call the first HTTP request it first assigns value back to my array then moves to the next API call but in this case, the data comes unsorted or did not assign the right id to my array.

```
this.imagesdataarray.forEach(imagedata => {
imagedata.imagesnamearray.forEach(imagename => {
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('userID', this.userid );
fd.append('projectID', imagedata.projectid);
fd.append('id', imagename.imageid);
fd.append('formFiles', imagename.image);


this.http
.post('http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/ImageProject/CreateProjectImages', fd)
.subscribe( async (res) => {
imagename.imageid = await res.result;
});

})
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you use async/await here. The Angular HTTPClient returns an observable for each of its request (post, put, delete...). You just need to subscribe to it. Please, try removing async and await from your code. Also I'd recommend reading a bit about rxjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **toPromise()** in this case with **await** keyword. It will wait for request to complete before moving to next loop and sending new request.

```
var res= await this.http
.post('http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/ImageProject/CreateProjectImages', fd).toPromise();

imagename.imageid = res.result;
```

Remember to use **async** keyword accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way:

```
   this.imagename.imageid = await new Promise<any>(resolve =>  this.http.post('http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/ImageProject/CreateProjectImages', fd)
    .subscribe( res => { resolve(res.result);
    //imagename.imageid = res.result;}
));
// Remaining code or function call
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, convert an Observable to Promise is not a good solution. The great of observables are that you can join, merge,forkjoin, swhitchMap..

In this case You should use map to create an array of observables and use [forkJoin](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/rxjs-forkjoin-combine-observables) to make an unique subscribe

```
//create an array of observables
const obs$=this.imagesdataarray.map(imagename =>{
    const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('userID', this.userid );
      fd.append('projectID', imagedata.projectid);
      fd.append('id', imagename.imageid);
      fd.append('formFiles', imagename.image);
      return this.http.post('http://.....', fd)
  })

//subscribe to a forkJoin of the array of observables
//"res" is an array with the response to the first call, the second call..
//so you can in subscribe use some like:
forkJoin($obs).subscribe((res:any[],index)=>{
   this.imagesdataarray[index].response=res[index];
})
```

BTW, you can use directy -it's not necesary formData-

```
const obs$=this.imagesdataarray.map(imagename =>{
    const fd = {'userID':this.userid,
                'projectID':imagedata.projectid,
                'id':imagename.imageid,
                'formFiles':imagename.image
               }
      return this.http.post('http:...', fd)
  })
```